# Can Meddling Mage Be Used as a Counter?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a player activated an [Æther Vial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212630) with two counters on it to drop in a [Meddling Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=179547) and named a spell already on the stack, would the named spell resolve?

Comment: A famous match once hinged on using a similar trick. It only worked due to an odd gap in the rules for madness, which has since been removed.

Comment: Brent, there seems to be a good answer here. Any chance you can mark it as accepted (click the tick)?

Comment: Sorry, still pretty new, I don't see where on my screen to mark this as accepted.

Comment: @BrentAllenHydorn: just below the answer's points there is a outline of a V, click there.

Answer (score 12):

The spell on the stack will resolve successfully, even if you name it with [Meddling Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=179547).

The rulings for [Meddling Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=179547) say the following:

> **2/1/2006** If you somehow manage to cast this while other spells are on the stack, those spells won't be countered.
>
> **5/1/2009** Spells with the chosen name that somehow happen to already be on the stack when Meddling Mage enters the battlefield are not affected by [Meddling Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=179547)'s ability.

To clarify the old "played" phrasing (which some people confuse with resolve), the Oracle text actually says:

> The named card can't be cast.

Since the named spell has already been cast, the existing spell on the stack will still be on the stack after [Meddling Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=179547) has entered, and will still resolve.

If you did have a creature that was able to counter or exile a spell on the stack (as opposed to the "named card can't be cast" effect) like [Spellstutter Sprite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=139429), you could put that into play with [Æther Vial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212630) and have it work they way you're intending.